# Laravel php editing items in an array inside and an array

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I want to edit a form that has questions and their answers in one swoop. So this is my laravel blade code

```
    <form action="{{action('QuizController@postEditQuiz', [$quiz_id])}}" method="post">
    @foreach ($questions  as $key => $question) 

    <input type="text" name="question[]" value="{{$question->question}}">   <br>                
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id[]" value="{{$question->question_id}}">   

    <input type="text" name="correct_answer" value="{{$correct_answer->answer}}"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="correct_answer_id" value="{{$correct_answer->id}}"><br>


  @foreach($incorrect_answers as $key => $incorrect)
            <input type="text" name="incorrect_answer[]" value="{{$incorrect->answer}}"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="incorrect_answer_id[]" value="{{$incorrect->id}}"><br>
@endforeach

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On the php side I can be able to update the question with no problem

```
$question                     = Request::get('question');
$question_id                  = Request::get('question_id');

    $count = count($question);

        for ($i=0;  $i<$count; $i++) {

        $update_question= DB::table('questions')
            ->where('question_id', $question_id[$i])
            ->update([
                'question' => $question[$i],
            ]);
  }
```

But updating each answer for each question is proving to be quite the challenge. For example updating the corect answer inside the above loop does not work.

```
 $question                     = Request::get('question');
 $question_id                  = Request::get('question_id');

    $count = count($question);

        for ($i=0;  $i<$count; $i++) {

        $update_question= DB::table('questions')
            ->where('question_id', $question_id[$i])
            ->update([
                'question' => $question[$i],
            ]);

    $update_correct_answer= DB::table('answers')
            ->where('question_id', $question_id[$i])
            ->where('correct', '1')
            ->update([
                'answer'      => $correct_answer,
            ]);
  }
```

How should I do it, Thanks.

Comment: What is the `column type for correct column`? Also include your full code, since we can't see what `$correct_answer` var is exactly

Comment: what are the correct flow to mean it worked and not? cause based on your code. it seems that working well enough